# HsqlException while trying to make a connection to a hsqldb in android studio

Tags: java, android, hsqldb

I am trying to create a connection to my hsqldb in android studio with a function:

```
private Connection connection() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:" + path + ";shutdown=true", "SA", "");
}
```

I am also calling the drivers with following code:

```
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver").newInstance();
```

And I'm getting the following error when I try the connection() function:

```
W/Adding Habit: java.sql.SQLException: error in script file line: 1 org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid 
property name
W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: error in script file line: 1 org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid 
property name
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source:125)
W/System.err:     at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source:12)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source:221)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source:47)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source:30)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
    at com.example.goodhabit.Persistence.HSQLDB.HabitHSQLDB.connection(HabitHSQLDB.java:26)
    at com.example.goodhabit.Persistence.HSQLDB.HabitHSQLDB.addHabit(HabitHSQLDB.java:68)
    at com.example.goodhabit.Logic.HabitManager.addHabit(HabitManager.java:21)
    at com.example.goodhabit.Presentation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
```

hsqldb version: 2.4.1

Can somebody please tell me why the message "error in script file line: 1" is being shown? I'm getting this message even if I remove my SC.script file from my assets/db/ directory. My script file contains are:

```
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.HABITS(ID INTEGER NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT 
NULL, TYPE INTEGER NOT NULL, MESSAGE VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, HR INTEGER NOT 
NULL, MINT INTEGER NOT NULL, STARTDATE VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, ENDDATE 
VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, DAYSCHECKEDIN INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
CREATE USER SA PASSWORD DIGEST 'd41d8cd98f00b274e9800998ecf8427e'
ALTER USER SA SET LOCAL TRUE
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
GRANT DBA TO SA
SET WRITE_DELAY 20
SET FILES SCALE 32
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
INSERT INTO HABITS VALUES(21, 'Code early morning', 1, 'Coding early morning 
increases productivity.', 6, 30, '01/03/2021', '20/06/2021', 10)
INSERT INTO HABITS VALUES(22, 'Drink milk', 1, 'Drinking milk strengthens 
bones.', 8, 00, '01/02/2021', '20/06/2021', 12)
```

Comment: This .script file is damaged. The first line should contain `SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDB78XXXXXXXX`. Delete the file and start again.

Comment: I tried deleteing the .script file and and strting again by adding that line but still got the same error. I'm getting this error even if there is no script file in my db folder. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The .script file of the database is created and managed by the engine. Do not try to change it. Use an absolute path in the DriverManager.getConnection(...). and check the database files on this path.

Comment: I’m a bit confused about that. Can you please give me an example of the absolute path in the statement DriverManager.get Connection(...)? Also do u mean that I cannot create a .script file from and need to work with the one made by the engine? Please help me coz I got a project due tomorrow and am stuck because of this.

Answer (score 0):

This .script file is damaged. The first line should contain SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDB78XXXXXXXX. Delete the file and start again.

The .script file of the database is created and managed by the engine. Do not try to change it. Use an absolute path in the DriverManager.getConnection(...). and check the database files on this path.

You need to read the HSQLDB Guide. Example of absolute path is `jdbc:hsqldb:file:/assets/dbdir/SC` and it begins with `/`.

If you are thinking of writing SQL statements for creating tables and data, prepare the database first using the DatabaseManagerSwing app (it part of HSQLDB), SHUTDOWN the database, then start accessing it from the studio.